# Keycloak debug level logs with jboss are cluttered

Tags: logging, jboss, keycloak

I am using `jboss/keycloak:15.0.2`. To comply with security requirements, I need to enable DEBUG level logs to log success messages for user login. The docker compose config looks like

```
  loginservice:
    image: my-image
    environment:
    - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm-export-deploy.json
    - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    - KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
    - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/loginadmin
    - SYS_PROPS=-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING
    - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
    - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://servername.net/keycloak/auth
    ports:
    - 7070:8080
```

However, as soon as the service comes up the logs are getting cluttered with repeated messaging of

```
08:00:30,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Executed scheduled task AbstractLastSessionRefreshStoreFactory$$Lambda$2097/0x0000000841707840
08:00:35,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
08:00:35,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
08:00:35,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.sessions.PersisterLastSessionRefreshStore] (Timer-2) Updating 0 userSessions with lastSessionRefresh: 1639123175
08:00:35,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
08:00:35,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper end
08:00:35,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Executed scheduled task AbstractLastSessionRefreshStoreFactory$$Lambda$2097/0x0000000841707840
08:00:40,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
08:00:40,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
08:00:40,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
08:00:40,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper end
08:00:40,986 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Executed scheduled task AbstractLastSessionRefreshStoreFactory$$Lambda$2097/0x0000000841707840
08:00:45,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
08:00:45,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
08:00:45,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
08:00:45,985 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper end
```

The events I enabled from keycloak UI:
[image]

Any clue whats up with the clutter and how can it be disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to enable DEBUG logs for all Keycloak packages. Just enabling it for `org.keycloak.events` is enough. This can be done by adding this JBOSS startup script to the Keycloak container:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.keycloak.events/:add(category=org.keycloak.events,level=DEBUG)
stop-embedded-server
```

This will capture most of the relevant events in the logs.

Or this can be specified as parameters to the start/start-dev command:

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --log-level="<root-level>,<org.category1>:<org.category1-level>"
```

e.g.

```
bin/kc.bat start-dev --log-level="WARN,org.keycloak.events:INFO,org.keycloak.saml:TRACE"
```

See the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging) for details.